# How do I craft a legendary weapon?

Tags: guild-wars-2

By all accounts, Legendary weapons are of equal power to Ascended (Pink) weapons, and so do not confer a *statistical* advantage over their less impressive Ascended companions, but their Legendary status brings other perks, like crazy visual effects, the ability to change their stats combinations, and more ephemeral bonuses like in-game prestige.

In the beta, there was some indication that these legendary weapons required a great deal of crafting to complete, at a great investment of time and materials. I've *also* heard that the way legendaries are obtained has *changed* between the betas and release.

So what's the skinny? How can one earn a legendary weapon for themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to some work with the Mystic Forge, we now have a decent understanding of how to craft Legendary Weapons.

As Brian mentions above (and as was true in the Beta), Legendary Weapons are created in the Mystic Forge in a complicated, multi-step process. Let's break it down.

1. **Level 80 Exotic "Precursor" Weapon.** (e.g., [Zap](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Zap) for [Bolt](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bolt), or [Dusk](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dusk) for [Twilight](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Twilight)) These can be randomly dropped by enemies in the world, randomly created with 4 high level rares of the same type (70+) in the mystic forge (some folk are assuming there's a Non-Random recipe as well), or bought off the Trading Post.
2. ***[Gift of Mastery](http://www.gw2db.com/items/70047-gift-of-mastery)***. This component is created in the Mystic Forge with Gift of Exploration,  A Bloodstone Shard, Gift of Battle, and 250 Obsidian Shards.

   - **[Gift of Exploration](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Exploration)**: Receive 2 when you 100% the World Map.
   - **[Gift of Battle](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_battle)**: Bought from WvWvW vendor for 500 Badges of Honor (earned from WvWvW and the 4 jumping puzzles).
   - **[Bloodstone Shard](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bloodstone_shard)**: Bought from [Miyani](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Miyani) for 200 Skillpoints.
   - **250 [Obsidian Shards](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Obsidian_Shard)**: 2100 Karma each. Bought from the Temple of Balthazar in Straits of Devastation. (525,000 total Karma!)
3. ***Gift of [Legendary Weapon Name]***. This component is created in the Mystic Forge with a Gift of Gathering, a Gift of Dungeons,  Icy Runestones, and a Superior Sigil unique to the Precursor Weapon.

   - **Gift of "Gathering"**: Dependent on the legendary in question. This is always a Gift of [Energy](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Energy), [Metal](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Metal), or [Wood](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Wood). Requires max level crafting, and a 10g recipe bought from [Miyani](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Miyani).
   - **Gift of "Dungeons"**: Also dependent on the legendary in question. This is a different [Miyani](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Miyani)-bought recipe that will always include Dungeon Tokens from explorable mode dungeons (or items *bought with* tokens) either 250 or 500, again, depending on the exact recipe. Will also require lots of materials as well, though the exact recipes run the gamut from [Steel Ingots](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Steel_Ingot) to [Unidentified Dyes](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Unidentified_Dye) (***not* from cooking!**).
   - **100 Icy Runestones**: High-end Crafting mat. Sold by Rojan the Penitent in Frostgorge Sound.
   - **Superior Sigil**: The exact superior sigil depends on the Legendary.
4. ***[Gift of Fortune](http://www.gw2db.com/items/63150-gift-of-fortune)***: This component is created in the Mystic Forge with Gift of Might, Gift of Magic, Mystic Clovers, and Globs of Ectoplasm.

   - **Gift of Magic**: Combine 250 each of grade 6 [Bones, Scales, Claws, and Fangs](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crafting_material#Fine_Crafting_Materials)
   - **Gift of Might**: Combine 250 each of grade 6 [Blood, Venom, Totems, and Dust](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crafting_material#Fine_Crafting_Materials).
   - **77 [Mystic Clovers](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Clover)**: Mystic Clovers can be randomly created in the mystic forge with a non-random recipe that will give random results.
   - **250 [Globs of Ectoplasm](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Ectoplasm)**: Rarely Obtained by salvaging Level 70+ Rare and Exotic Equipment.

#### Finally, combine the 4 items above in the Mystic Forge.

Voila. Legendary. Easy, right? (On everything but your time and your wallet!)

Comment: You mean In game wallet right ? Is there any material for crafting a legendary weapon that is only obtained via real currency purchases?

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins Correct. You don't need to buy gems to make a legendary.

Answer (score 4):

So far all legendary weapons are obtained by crafting three "gifts" and combining them with a specific exotic weapon in the [Mystic Forge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Forge). The process requires a lot of materials, so I've provided a tree here:

*[Legendary weapon](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Legendary_Weapon)*

- Gift of Mastery

  - Gift of Battle (traded for 500 [Badges of Honor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Badge_of_Honor) in WvW, requires level 80 and WvW rank 14 or higher)
  - Gift of Exploration (2 received for 100% world completion)
  - [Bloodstone Shard](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bloodstone_Shard) (bought from [Miyani](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Miyani) for 200 skill points)
  - 250 [Obsidian Shards](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Obsidian_Shard)
- Gift of Fortune

  - Gift of Might

    - 250 [Ancient Bones](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ancient_Bone)
    - 250 [Vicious Claws](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vicious_Claw)
    - 250 [Vicious Fangs](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vicious_Fang)
    - 250 [Armored Scales](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Armored_Scale)
  - Gift of Magic

    - 250 [Piles of Crystalline Dust](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Pile_of_Crystalline_Dust)
    - 250 [Elaborate Totems](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Elaborate_Totem)
    - 250 [Powerful Venom Sacs](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Powerful_Venom_Sac)
    - 250 [Vials of Powerful Blood](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vial_of_Powerful_Blood)
  - 77 [Mystic Clovers](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Clover)
  - 250 [Globs of Ectoplasm](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Ectoplasm)
- Gift of *(Legendary weapon name)*

  - 100 [Icy Runestones](http://www.gw2db.com/items/70049-icy-runestone-s)
  - *crafted gathering gift*
  - *crafted dungeon gift*
  - *specific superior sigil*
- *[exotic precursor weapon](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Legendary_precursor)*

Each crafting gift first requires a recipe, which can be bought for 10 gold from Miyani near the Mystic Forge. For more information on the weapon-specific gifts, please refer to http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/64363-legendary-weapons-guide/.

Update: [gw2legendary.com](http://gw2legendary.com/) is a great, interactive resource for planning and evaluating the cost of your legendary weapon based on current market prices.

Comment: The mystic forge requires 4 items. That accounts for the first and the second, but what about the other two?

Comment: Good point Raven. I updated this answer to reflect that you also need a Bloodstone Shard and an exotic weapon (which appears to be a different one for each legendary weapon).

Comment: Mystic forge also requires a mystic coin to be able to use it, these are obtained through completing daily achievments etc.
Atleast that's what the mystic coins suggest when you receive them.

Comment: So Scuttlebutt is coming back that **this answer is not correct**. Case in Point, Dawn (Exotic precursor to the Legendary Greatsword Sunrise) does not have a recipe with bloodstone shards. [(The forge simply won't allow it)](http://imgur.com/CvW1P)

Comment: Interesting, that contradicts everything I've seen so far. I wonder if you have to make something else with the Bloodstone Shard before using it in the Mystic Forge. It's also possible (but unlikely) that it's a bug, or that Arenanet has disabled the crafting of legendary weapons to prevent them from being acquired so early in the game's life. I'll do some research and keep up with the topic so that I can properly update my answer.

Comment: Brian - I've added a disclaimer to your answer to indicate it has not been confirmed on live. This question has earned over 11,000 views, and I'd rather we not promote demonstrably false information, given the number of people stumbling upon this answer.

Comment: Thanks Raven. I'll update it again when more is certain. A sentence on the official wiki recently theorized that it actually requires "an item (name unknown) created from: Gift of Exploration (100% world completion), Gift of Battle (500 Badges from WvW), Bloodstone Shard (200 skill points), and 250 Obsidian Shards (bought for 2100 karma from a vendor on Orr)"

Comment: I updated this answer with new information. I hope this helps.

Comment: The first legendary weapons were created today after a bug that prevented Obsidian Shards from stacking was fixed. Here's a post by the person with the first Sunrise explaining how he did it: http://www.guildwars2guru.com/topic/68910-the-long-awaited-legendary-greatsword-sunrise/